# How to force GCC to warn about usage of a class function?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++03, pragma, gcc-warning

Using GCC 4.8.*, when the warning `-Wfloat-equal` is activated, the compiler warns about strict comparisons between floting point number, like in the following example:

```
double x = 3.14159;
double y = 1.11111;
if(x == y) // <-- this induces a warning
{ /* ... */ }
```

Now, imagine I want a class containing double variables and defining the equality operator:

```
class Complex // (it's only an example)
{
  private:
    double re;
    double im;
  public:
    bool operator == (Complex const& z) const;
};
bool Complex::operator == (Complex const& z) const
{
  return (this->re == z.re) && (this->im == z.im);
}
```

This does exactly what I expect. Of course, it induces a warning when I compile the class. In order to avoid it (because I understand the warning, thanks to the compiler, but I want to do that, and I don't want to continue to see the warning), I inform the compiler by this way:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
bool Complex::operator == (Complex const& z) const
{
  return (this->re == z.re) && (this->im == z.im);
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Okay, I don't have the warning when I compile my `Complex.cpp` file. But it's still dangerous to **use** the operator `==` on complex numbers, exaclty like it's dangerous to use operator `==` on double numbers (it's the reason for the existence of the option `-Wfloat-equal`). Then, my question:

**Is it possible to have a GCC warning (activated by `-Wfloat-equal`) where the operator `==` on complex numbers is used ?** It's not the existence of the operator I want to warn, but the usage.

*Note: I defined the symmetric operator as a class member, but I'm open to have a class function `bool equals(...) const` called by a `bool operator == (Complex const&,Complex const&)` if it can simplify my expected behavior.*

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reasons.*

Comment: Can it be an error?

Comment: @iBug: I'm interested by a solution giving an error, but it's a problem for my nightly builds if a simple warning stop them.

Comment: I think that the usefulness of -Wfloat-equal would be greatly enhanced if it could filter out comparisons with precise floating point literals, in particular 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work ([live on gcc4.8.5](https://godbolt.org/g/BqALgU)):

```
__attribute__((warning ("your message")))
bool operator == (Complex const& z) const;
```

of course, you'll need to make sure the offending statement doesn't get optimized out ..

As it is, you'll need to dis/enable it manually (via some define) ... I don't know if gcc allows inspecting if a warning has been enabled or not.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to know if a warning is activated or not. But I use CMake to manage the build, and I manages my warning activation through CMake. It's easy to add this kind of hand-made activation.

Comment: This works for me too, but now I can't disable this warning if I know what I do when I compare complex numbers. :-p

Comment: you’re right; but you could write an explicit comparator a.exact_cmp(b), or exact(a==b) in that case

Comment: another alternative, would be to have two non member operator==, the non warning variant being activated via a local using directive...

Comment: Hmm, interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `Exactly` wrapper type that expresses the intent clearly?

```
template<typename T>
struct Exactly : T
{
    explicit Exactly(T const& value) : T(value) {}
};

class Complex
{
    double re;
    double im;

public:
    Complex(double re, double im) : re(re), im(im) {}

    // Non-members require either friend access or public getters.
    double real() const { return re; }
    double imag() const { return im; }
};

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
bool operator == (Complex const& a, Exactly<Complex> const& b)
{
    return (a.real() == b.real()) && (a.imag() == b.imag());
}
// two more overloads for completeness
bool operator == (Exactly<Complex> const& a, Complex const& b)
{
    return (a.real() == b.real()) && (a.imag() == b.imag());
}
bool operator == (Exactly<Complex> const& a, Exactly<Complex> const& b)
{
    return (a.real() == b.real()) && (a.imag() == b.imag());
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

You can then also predefine constants like this (e.g. locally or in a namespace):

```
Exactly<Complex> exactlyOne(Complex(1.0, 0.0));
```

And add a "maker" function so that you don't have to repeat the type name such as `Complex`:

```
template<typename T>
Exactly<T> exactly(T const& value)
{
    return Exactly<T>(value);
}
```

`operator !=` left as an exercise to the reader.

*Minor update*: If you want to allow `operator ==` without `Exactly`, but with a warning, then you need to add another overload `operator ==(Complex const& a, Complex const& b)` with the attribute mentioned by Massimiliano Janes. Seems unnecessary though.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/drMJJH)